# import javascript functions from file on a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-redux

TL;DR Is there a way to import a JS file into your react application from a server?

Hi, I am building a web site that is 99% static Html with just a few sections where I need vanilla JavaScript or perhaps JQuery. I am also building a React-redux SPA that is basically an editor for some of the static content. The editor will be hosted in the same place as the static website.

I would like to be able to share some JS files between them. For example, I have some complex JS that performs calculations that need to be performed both in the editor and for displaying dynamically calculated values in the "viewable" content.

I need to be able to 'import' those into my reducers or business logic classes in the editor. Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: I would like to be able to load the calculation JS at runtime, so that I can change the calculations and see the changes reflected in both the view pages and application without having to recompile the app.

Comment: Doesn't `import` work?

Comment: I admit I haven't tried it, but the files need to live outside the application if they are going to be shared. How would import know where to find them?

Comment: You can install them locally `npm install ./path/to/folder` make sure it has a package.json

Comment: Now that I think about it, what I said isn't quite true. I do want to be able to update the JS files outside the application and see the changes reflected in the app, if that is possible. I am trying to make it as easy as possible on myself. I don't think what I want to do is even possible. I would need a concept like an Interface to program against and a concrete implementation I can load at runtime.